# How to correctly implement CKEditor v3 into ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, wrapper

I'm not so much into JavaScript, so I'm not able to use the new CKEditor right away. Until now I was using the FCKEditor ASP.net wrapper, which works fine for me. Unfortunatly the official wrapper is not for version 3.

I've googled http://syrinxckeditor.codeplex.com/ but the project is over a year old and seems like a beta to me.

Is there a stable ASP.net wrapper for the CKEditor available? Or how can I implement it into my ASP.net Webapplication project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is updated after each release: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15882